# Java Script Promises - If Statement Return Best Practices

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm writing a `node.js` function that returns a different promise depending on a condition, the cod:

```
if(condition){
    return promise.then(() => {
        return Promise.resolve(value)
    })
}else{
    return anotherPromise
}
```

Now the problem is that if the condition is true, I need to something after the promise is fulfilled, but in the other case I just return the promise, so the `eslint` tells me that it's a bad practice to nest promises. So this code won't work for me:

```
(() => {
    if(condition){
        return promise
    }
    }else{
        return anotherPromise
    }
}).then(() => {
    return Promise.resolve(value)
})
```

Because using this code the `then` callback will be executed in the two cases.

> **What is the best practice to handle this case?**

Comment: Is switching to `async/await` an option?

Comment: No because I'm writing this function for Firebase Cloud Functions and they use ES6 and that doesn't support `async/await`.

Comment: @AmeerTaweel just compile your javascript so you can use async await?..

Comment: Is the `Promise.resolve(value)` above really part of the code or just a placeholder for some other logic? If it's part of the code, why don't you just return `value` at that point? there is no need to wrap this actually.

Comment: @Sirko it's just a placeholder, the real value is returned after reading a value from the database.

Comment: @briosheje do you mean writing code with es8 and compiling it to es6?

Comment: Just write whatever js you need and compile it to whatever your target requires, you may use any javascript compiler or just the typescript one if you feel you want to use typescript. As @Sirko mentioned, async await as an option is likely the best and most comfortable solution.

Comment: @briosheje But how to compile my code from es8 to es6? Is there a particular tool?

Comment: https://babeljs.io/

Comment: @AmeerTaweel https://babeljs.io/ . If you want to play a bit with presets (you need to add the ES2017 preset), go here: https://es6console.com/ . Just write your code, hit transform and check how it is transformed.

Comment: @briosheje The code babel spits out is generally disgusting to look at, I wouldn't recommend it. Also, using `async` and `await` without understanding promises is probably not the greatest idea.

Comment: @AmeerTaweel To be honest, your initial solution looks the best. If the chained promise will always be used after `promise`, you could assign that to it and have no nesting when checking the condition.

Comment: @destoryer are we talking about the clever approach or..? babel is just **another** alternative to other existing tools, if you need to deal with tons of promises and / or nested promises, async await is likely one of the cleverest scenarios available for tons of reasons. You don't need to look at the code that babel spits you, you may want to do that to actually understand what is happending behind the scenes :).

Comment: @briosheje Don't get me wrong, I very much advocate the use of `async`/`await`, but not before one feels comfortable with vanilla promises.

Comment: Can you post your actual code? The one in your question doesn't cause an eslint warning.

Comment: @Bergi it actually does, because I'm nesting promises, no need for actual code, the important is the idea.

Comment: @AmeerTaweel I cannot reproduce on https://eslint.org/demo. What rule is this? And you're not actually nesting promises anywhere - maybe you are nesting promise *callbacks* if this code is inside another `then` callback, but you haven't shown that.

Comment: @Bergi eslint considers it a bad practice to attach a `then` to a `promise` inside another promise since the `then` method returns a `promise`.

Comment: @AmeerTaweel Sure, but a) that should not apply if the inner promise is in a conditional branch (read: **I** consider the rule broken) b) the code you posted shows no sign of being "inside another promise".

Comment: @Bergi It's my fault I should have posted a more clear code, the code above should be inside a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use classic (ES6 / ES2015+) Promise syntax you have to chain promises (nothing bad with it!).

But you have also option to split the code into functions to gain readability and [avoid nesting issues](https://www.datchley.name/promise-patterns-anti-patterns/):

```
const firstCase = () => ... // returning a promise
const secondCase = () => ... // returning a promise

if (condition) {
  return firstCase()
} else {
  return secondCase()
}
```

But with ES7/ES2016+ you can use [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await) syntax:

```
// in a "async" function
async function main() {
  if (condition) {
    await promise // if you need the promise result, you can assign it
    return value // the result of an async function is always a Promise.
  } else {
    return anotherPromise
  }
}
```

or mix both solutions.

Comment: Actually I guess the first solution makes the code more readable. (Since I can't use `async/await`)

Answer (score 0):

A simple suggestion, (this should work) pass the condition in the resolve's argument and check it in the **then** block. The pseudo-code below will clarify it better:

```
(() => {
    if(condition){
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            //Some tasks
            resolve(condition)

            //Some reject condition
            reject()
        })
    }
    else {
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            //Some tasks
            resolve(condition)

            //Some reject condition
            reject()
        })
    }
}).then((condition) => {
     if(condition) {
         //Do something
     }
     else {
        //Do Nothing
     }
})
```

Comment: I am not sure what problem is your code solving. Promises are still nested.

Comment: Was focusing on this part of your question "Now the problem is that if the condition is true, I need to something after the promise is fulfilled, but in the other case I just return the promise."

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to get what do you mean by Promises are still nested.

Comment: @RajaNandSharma You haven't really changed anything in the code.

Answer (score 0):

> eslint tells me that it's a bad practice to nest promises.

Just <s>tell it to *shut *** up*</s> disable the linter on this statement. Promises have the ability to be nested precisely so that you can nest them when you need it, and this is one of those cases. Your code is fine.

Comment: I know this won't affect code performance, but I'm trying to use the best practices for readability and clean code.

Comment: @AmeerTaweel There's nothing wrong with nesting if control flow requires it. Promises are designed be nestable for this exact reason. If you want clean (but verbose) code, factor out the inner callback into an extra named function. If you want readable code, use `async`/`await`, but in the comments you said you can't do that.

Comment: actually I guess it's the best solution to create an extra function just for readability, I know that the code will work perfectly while nesting promises, but eslint keeps showing me that annoying warning so I was wondering what is the better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are over complicating it. The then method already returns a promise so you don’t need to put a Promise.resolve inside it.

You can for simplicity do

```
return condition
  ? promise.then(() => value)
  : anotherPromise
```